# Probability to fit $1950$ items in a box that hold $1880$. Risk $5$%

Tags: probability

If I buy $1950$ plates to fill a box that hold $1880$ what is the probability that $1950$ is enough if the risk of dropping a plate is $5$% per plate?

The answer is $F_z(-2,81)=0,0025$

I just don't know how to get there and don't know where to start looking for a way of calculating this.

Comment: Let $Y$ be the number of unbroken plates. Then $Y$ has binomial distribution $n=1950$, $p=0.95$. We want $\Pr(Y\ge 1880)$. You are expected to use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to use the [normal approximation to the binomial distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)  The expected number of plates to drop is $1950 \cdot 0.05$  The standard deviation is $\sqrt{1950 \cdot 0.05 \cdot (1-0.05)}$